# Roast Chicken vs Roasted Chicken

Tags: grammar, word-choice, past-participles

I was reading the "Oxford Word Skills" book when I got a question:

Since "roast" itself can act as an adjective (and of course as a verb), is it correct to say either "roasted chicken" or "roast chicken"? Or, the first option is not correct? The book has offered the second phrase, so which one is a more proper word to use? As a general question, if a word has a verb and an adjective form (like what we see here), and since P.P of verbs can also act as an adjective, is there any rule to use one over the other? Or is it optional? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Wait several hours, preferably a day or two, before accepting an answer -- so as to give late comers a chance to read the post and attempt an answer.

Comment: That's OK, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the past participle is one way to use a verb as an adjective but in some cases the base of the verb is used instead:

- Roast Chicken
- Open Book
- Corrupt Judge

There is no rule as far as I know, it's just a quirk of English.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

All verbs do not necissarily have an adjective form.
In fact - because forming adjectives is so irregular and there are many ways to do it (adding -ed, -ing or other suffixes; adding prefixes; even stand-alones like comparative and superlative adjectives) it may be less confusing learning adjectives as their own part of speech and not as a verb form. (if that is what you are doing)

Here are some links I think you'll find helpful:

- [Discussion on using base form verbs as adjectives](http://englishharmony.com/base-form-verb-as-adjective/)
- [Article on ways adjectives are formed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-forms)
- [A list of adjectives ending in -ed (and -ing if you need that)](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Adjectives_ED_ING.htm)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Though I am not sure whether all verbs necessarily have an adjective form in English but if not so, considering what you said as I understand, even if the word doesn't have an adjective form, we can use the base form of the verb as an adjective as a general (colloquial) idea? Am I right?

Comment: Sorry - I will try to clarify my answer.

Comment: This was, in fact, my first answer on a stackexchange forum, so can I get some clarification on why my answer was downvoted? My assumption is it was because someone thought the question was a duplicate - but it struck me as distinct. The OP wasn't asking for an analysis they appeared to be studying english as a second language and had a much more practical question about everyday usage. Either way, I'd take it as a kindness if I could get a reason for being downvoted - I'm simply curious, no ill will.

Comment: I also wonder who has downvoted your answer and why?! It's weird...